# How do I find out the number of X fan on a facebook page, and if they were referred, if so, by whom?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-like

Background: My employer is running a contest and wants to find out who the 1000th person to 'like' the page is, and if they were referred by someone. Is that functionality build in already, or does an app have to be written to find out this info?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get a list of page fans or the order in which they became fans, but you can track new fans who like your page via capturing the edge.create event in the javascript API when they click the Like button. 
You could also check the current like count to come to some sort of conclusion about which order users became fans and which 'number' fan they are

I must point out though that running such a competition is expressly forbidden by Facebook's promotion guidelines: https://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php

Comment: Thanks for the guideline link. We're not really running a competition. We just want to know who is the thousanth fan so we can send them stuff. Just like radio stations when they ask you to be the "n" caller.

Comment: I think that still counts as a promotion, but regardless of whether it's policy compliant, it's not actually possible except via workarounds such as the above 
You'd probably find it much easier to track comments by users on posts your page makes, likes of those posts, etc, because those will be static in the API